# Trying to sum different columns number at the same time

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, data.table

**Data**

Consider you have this data.table or dataframe (i'm working with data.table):

```
a <- c(1, 6.7, 7.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.2, 4.2, 5, 6.6,6.7) 
b <- c(2,5.0, 3.5, 4.9, 7.8, 9.3, 8.0, 7.8, 8.0,10)
c <- c(3, 7.0, 5.5, 7.2, 7.7, 7.2, 8.0, 7.6, 7,6.7) 
d <- c(4, 7.0, 7.0, 7.0, 6.9, 6.8, 9.0, 6.0, 6.6,6.7) 
df <- data.frame(rbind(a,b,c,d))

  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X7  X8  X9  X10
a  1 6.7 7.0 6.5 7.0 7.2 4.2 5.0 6.6  6.7
b  2 5.0 3.5 4.9 7.8 9.3 8.0 7.8 8.0 10.0
c  3 7.0 5.5 7.2 7.7 7.2 8.0 7.6 7.0  6.7
d  4 7.0 7.0 7.0 6.9 6.8 9.0 6.0 6.6  6.7
```

**Problem**

I'm trying to sum X3 and X4 for the first line, X3 and X4 and X5 for the second, etc...

**What i did**

I have a vector called iter :

```
iter <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

And what i did is a for loop

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
df$sum[i] <- sum(as.numeric(df[i,2:(2+iter[i])]),na.rm=T)}
```

Do you know a way to do it without a for loop ?

**Expected output**

```
output 
   13.7  #correspond to df[1,X3]+df[1,X4]
   13.4  #correspond to df[2,X3]+df[2,X4]+df[2,X5]
   27.4  #correspond to df[3,X3]+df[3,X4]+df[3,X5]+df[3,X6]
   37.4  #correspond to df[4,X3]+df[4,X4]+df[4,X5]+df[4,X6]+df[4,X7]
```

**EDIT**

```
iter <- c(1,2,3,4)
```

is completely arbitrary here, so i need a solution for any value of iter

Comment: @lmo try now i edited the data frame and the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` with accumulate=TRUE and then extract the values.

```
# initialize iter variable
iter <- 1:4

# calculate cumulative row sums, dropping initial list element
vals <- Reduce("+", df[2:10], accumulate=TRUE)[-1]

# pull out what you want with recursive indexing and sapply
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) vals[[c(iter[x], x)]])
[1] 13.7 13.4 27.4 34.7
```

Comment: same here,  if i want to sum with iter <- c(2,5,4,3) it seems to not work

Comment: Pretty simple change, I guess as long as you want the cumulative sum. I swapped `c(x, x)` with `c(iter[x], x)` in the recursive index.

Comment: Can the reduce deals with `NA` ?

Comment: "+" cannot deal with NAs. You could do some manipulation beforehand to convert NAs to 0, though.

Answer (score 3):

Elements of `df` are factors which complicates the solution a bit. First I turn the relevant columns to numeric matrix.

Edit: with updated version of `df` without factors

```
mat <- sapply(df[,-1], as.numeric)
rowSums(mat*cbind(TRUE, lower.tri(mat[,-1], diag = TRUE)))

[1] 13.7 13.4 27.4 34.7
```

Using arbitrary iter:

```
index.mat = t(sapply(iter, function(x){rep(c(TRUE,FALSE), times = c(x+1, ncol(df)-x))}))
rowSums(df[,-1]*index.mat)

20.2 38.5 34.6 27.9
```

Comment: Woops, one more thing, the diagonal here was arbitrary, if i want to sum with `iter <- c(2,5,4,3)` it seems to not work

Answer (score 1):

What about this?
If iter specifies the # of columns:

```
iter <- c(2,5,4,2)
  sapply(1: length(iter),(function(i){
    ri <- iter[i]
      sum(df[i, 3:(3+ri-1)])
  }))
```

If you use it for the order of the rows (like, for reordering the rows in the dataframe)

```
iter <- c(1,2,3,4)
sapply(1: length(iter),(function(i){
  ri <- iter[i]
    sum(df[ri, 3:(3+i)])
}))
```